# How to apply a jQuery function to a child page in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's a brainteaser:

I have an iframe in a window, and a navbar that links to it:

```
<div class="nav">
<a href="link.html" target="iframe-content" id='debug">#Debug<a>
</div>

<iframe name="iframe-content" src="page.html"></iframe>
```

I've then got a simple jQuery function to inset a class when a link in the nav is clicked.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#debug").click(function() {
        $('body').toggleClass("debug");
    });
});
```

Now my question is how do I get the toggleclass to apply to the inline frame (page.html) and not the parent page?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$('body').toggleClass("debug");
```

To

```
$('#debug').contents().find('body').toggleClass("debug");
```

Check out the [jQuery documentation for `.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)

Comment: I get "Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null"." with this method?

Answer (score 1):

```
var $iframe = $('iframe[name="iframe-content"]').contents();
$iframe.find('#debug').click(function(){
    $iframe.find('body').toggleClass('debug');
});
```

Use [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)

From the docs:

> The `.contents()` method can also be used to get the content document of an iframe, if the iframe is on the same domain as the main page.

Comment: Thanks, I think this would work if the link was inside the iframe?